# How to find the vector along which the directional derivative does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have been doing Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds on my own and am stumped by yet another question. The question is as follows:

> Let $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(x, y) = (x, y + x^2)$ and $f(x, y) = \dfrac{xy(x^2 - y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} $ if $(x, y) \ne (0,0)$ and $f({\bf 0}) = 0$. $h = f \circ g$. Show that directional deriatives of $f, g$ exist everywhere but $\exists {\bf u}\ne {\bf 0}$ such that $h'({\bf 0}; {\bf u})$ does not exist.

I have evaluated $h({\bf 0}) = 0$. Hence,
\begin{align}
h'({\bf 0}; {\bf u}) &= \lim\limits_{\lambda \to 0} \frac{h(\lambda {\bf u}) - 0}{\lambda} = \lim\limits_{\lambda \to 0} \frac{f \circ g (\lambda {\bf u})}{\lambda}\\
&= \lim\limits_{\lambda \to 0} \frac{f(\lambda x, \lambda y + \lambda^2 x^2)}{\lambda} = \lim \limits_{ \lambda \to 0}\frac{\lambda x (\lambda y + \lambda^2 x^2)(\lambda^2 x^2 - (\lambda y + \lambda^2 x^2)^2)}{\lambda \cdot (\lambda^2 x^2 + (\lambda y + \lambda^2 x^2)^2}\\
& = \lim \limits_{\lambda \to 0} \frac{\lambda^2(xy + \lambda x^3)\lambda^2(x^2 - (y + \lambda x^2)^2)}{\lambda^3(x^2 + (y + \lambda x^2)^2)}
\end{align}

The only way $h'({\bf 0}; {\bf u})$ might not exist is if the denominator converges to $0$. If $(x, y)$ is a unit vector then the denominator always tends to $1$. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? At first glance it seems the partial derivatives of $h$ exist and are continuous on a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$, which is enough to guarantee the Fréchet derivative exists, hence all the directional derivatives too.

Comment: @GoodBoy No, there is no typo. That is exactly what is so confusing about it for me.